# Ошибки при поиске всех файлов на диске

Tags: c++

Написал простейшую программку поиска всех файлов на диске, но не всегда она работает корректно. Поиск прерывается по неизвестной причине, и должного выхода из программы не происходит.

1. Поиск прерывается когда попадается папка с ограниченными правами доступа,
   при попытке войти с проводника пишет "Нет разрешений на доступ к этой папке".
   По каким атрибутам проверять такие папки чтобы обойти, и можно ли получить к ним доступ(очень желательно)?
2. Например находит папку с именем "Group - 0602537195633",
   В консоль выводит "Group ?- 0602537195633" очень много раз со знаком вопроса перед тире,
   после чего завершается. Такое было и на другом диске тоже поставил знак вопроса перед символом, что это такое?
3. Как узнать по какой причине произошла ошибка если ни на какие "cout-триггеры" не реагирует?
4. Еще слышал что проблемы могут возникнуть с длиной пути, у меня массив определен как "char LocalPath[MAX_PATH]"
   При копировании Windows иногда выдает что длинна пути слишком велика и прерывает копирование, зато файловые менеджеры как-то решают эту проблему, как?

Функции используемые в программе:
FindFirstFile
FindNextFile
FindClose
lstrcat
lstrcmp

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Я бы добавил к вопросу еще и язык, на котором написана программа, и операционку. Чисто из советов "в вакууме" - можно посоветовать обработку ошибок при попытке доступа к папке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Иметь необходимые права
2. Похоже на беды с Юникодом. Нужно использовать юникодные версии функций (настроить среду разработки (вы не указали, чем собираете)) или внаглую дописывать суффикс W - `FindFirstFileW`. И с консолью общаться с помощью `wcout`
3. WTF? Обработка ошибок подробно описана в статьях MSDN к функциям, которые вы используете. Стандартный паттерн - функция возвращяет состояние ошибки (это может быть и `NULL`, `FALSE` и не-ноль - читайте мануал), после чего вы вызываете `GetLastError` и узнаете код ошибки. Его смысл можно посмотреть в том же MSDN (сюрприз, правда?), или преобразовать в текст с помощью `FormatMessage`
4. Удивительно, но на эту тему есть [многабукв](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd) в том же самом MSDN

Вывод - При работе с API - принцип RTFM - это друг, товаришь и брат. Не пренебрегайте им, особенно если это API в исполнении M$.

Только никогда не читайте уродливый перевод, который M$ подсовывает, увидев русскую локаль в браузере:

> Это функции управления файлами, которые больше не имеют ограничений на
> максимальную длину _ пути , если вы явно задействуете поведение пути:
> копифилев, CopyFile2, копифиликсв, креатефилев, CreateFile2,
> креатехардлинкв, креатесимболиклинкв, делетефилев, FindFirstFileW,
> FindFirstFileExW, FindNextFileW, GetFileAttributesW,
> GetFileAttributesExW, SetFileAttributesW, GetFullPathNameW,
> GetLongPathNameW, MoveFileW, MoveFileExW, MoveFileWithProgressW,
> ReplaceFileW, SearchPathW, FindFirstFileNameW, FindNextFileNameW.

Это - позорище. Избавиться от него можно, найдя в URL `ru-ru` и заменив него на `en-us`

Comment: gdb - Вы кросавчег! про юнникодные версии функций то я и не подумал!

Comment: 1) Вы же понимаете, что это вопрос типичного взломщика и вам здесь на него не ответят?

2)Если в папку не удалось зайти, вы получите ошибку, после чего папку придется пропустить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

1.
а) Как получить права, не имея прав?
б) Как обойти такие папки по какому атрибуту?

"уродливый перевод" это дело эстетики, для знатоков английского конечно это наверно дико выглядит, но это только кажется.

Comment: @KoTTBarsik плохой перевод (особенно машинный) искажает смысл написанного, увеличивая непонимание на порядок. Единственный способ нормально развиваться в программировании - учить английский язык.

Comment: Возможно ли еще задействовать юникод не меняя код например дописать компилятору команду какую. Использую mingw, прописываю все в обычном bat файле.

Comment: Я вот не пойму как хранятся атрибуты в dwFileAttributes, это битовая маска, там только один аттрибут, или несколько можно?

Comment: 1) Нет, потому что типы данных другие, программу нужно адаптировать.

2) Это маска: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants

Comment: Все равно не пойму как работает dwFileAttributes.
У обычной папки атрибут 16d, у той что недоступна так же 16d,
так как же ее игнорировать если у них маска одна и та же?

Comment: Пишу второй раз - если зайти в папку не получилось, анализируйте ошибку. Если ошибка - нет прав - значит, пропускаете папку.

Comment: То что чекать через GetLastError это понятно. Но все же, я просто хочу разобраться, ведь если взять папку у нее FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, но ведь у папки может быть и атрибут HIDDEN и READONLY и другие, а тут либо то, либо другое, не понимаю! Я думал что dwFileAttributes хранится битовая маска по которой можно было узнать "ВСЕ АТРИБУТЫ" файла или папки, но там просто целое число.